# Laravel API Authentication issue

Tags: api, laravel-5

I have a Laravel APi Route. i am using simple API authentication with inbuilt token system.

My API route looks like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['subdomain_setup','auth:api'],'prefix'=>'v1'], function () {    
        Route::get('getCoupons', 'Api\CouponAPI@getCoupons');   
});
```

When i am accessing this route it says

```
Unknown column 'api_token' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `api_token` =
```

But api_token is there in the user table. I don't know why i am getting this error.

My User Model look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password'
    ];

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 'api_token'
    ];



    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function($user){
            $user->act_token=str_random(40);
        });
    }

    public function confirmEmail()
    {
        $this->verified = true;
        $this->act_token =  null;

        $this->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you refresh your database after adding `api_token` to the migration ?

Comment: @Maraboc I did not used migration to create the column, i added it manually to the db